# Find out if stdout is terminal or pipe

Tags: node.js

How to detect if the type of the process.stdout/stdin is a terminal or a pipe/file? A snipped in JavaScript is required:

```
function isTerminal(){ 
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to identity if the type of the process.stdout is a pipe/file 
would be process.stdout.isTTY (0.8 +):

```
$ node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)" | cat
false 
$ node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)"
true
```

You can also test the following with the tty module for finer grained control:

```
if (require('tty').isatty(1)) {
    // terminal
}
```